# Python: Find number given array within two-dimensional array

Tags: python

so if i want to find a in b and if b contains a element, I would like to print the whole array that contains a. In this case, I would like to print ['1','2'] twice.

```
 a = ['1','2','3','4','5']
 b = [['1','2'],['7,'8']]

 c = 0
  while c < len(a):
    if a[c] in b[0:-1]:
       print b that contains a
    c+=1
```

Comment: What if `a = ['0','2','3','4','5']`?

Comment: Then the array ['1','2'] is printed only once

Answer (score 0):

So you will need to actually reference the objects within b, which in this case are arrays.  So this will only work with two dimensional arrays.

```
a = ['1','2','3','4','5']
b = [['1','2'],['7','8']]
c = 0
while c < len(a):
   for arr in b:
       if a[c] in arr:
   print arr that contains a
c+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through all lists in `b` and check if `a[c]` is present in that list.

```
a = ['1','2','3','4','5']
b = [['1','2'],['7','8']]

c = 0
while c < len(a):
    for x in b:
        if a[c] in x:
            print(x)
    c+=1
```